Get octet-stream with ExecuteAsync from RestSharp without headers
I use RestSharp in version 111.2.0.
All our requests are build in this way:
internal async Task<byte[]> GetFileAsync(int documentId)
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{_apiPath}/document-files/{documentId}", Method.Get);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream");

    RestResponse response = await mRestClient.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true);
    ErrorHandling(response);

    return response.RawBytes;
}

So, really simple approach. We have a handler written, that makes log files and so on in the ErrorHandling-method. When we donwload a file this way it is "corrupted" by the octet-stream headers. These headers are inside the Content and inside the RawBytes properties.
The file then looks like this:
--69d36367-8ab0-4b7c-a718-668f7542e836
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="MG Test2.pdf"
 
%PDF-1.7
...
%%EOF
 
--69d36367-8ab0-4b7c-a718-668f7542e836--

But the beginning of the real file is the %PDF-1.7 and %%EOF should be the end of the file.
Naturally I could cut it out by hand... but that is not really a good approach, is it? There are coursing some examples in the net for the downloading of files, using the DownloadDataAsync for example. But that does not return a Response but throws errors itself and would require a completely new handling and try catches, etc.
Btw... if I don't add the header by hand I get a 406 error. So it is needed.
Anyone an idea what could be a better way of getting the file than to cut it out myself of the response?
EDIT: Sorry, I found the error and that was on upload. The error only existed on files that I uploaded myself right before. I uploaded them with Request.AddFile(...) instead of Request.AddParameter(...) and that seemed to be the wrong way. I corrected that and now the error is gone.

Maybe you should do it as RestClient it does? https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/RestClient.Async.cs#L45

couldn't really reproduce with default asp.net WebAPI controller from the other end sending a pdf file

I don't know what the company used at their side of the API. But I cannot take a look at their servers. :/

@MarcelGrüger maybe use vanilla BCL or Postman to get the whole response...I think the extra --69d36367-8ab0-4b7c-a718-668f7542e836 thrown by the server prevents RestSharp successful parsing

The response is a multipart form, not a plain file content. It looks more like a server issue.

Yeah seems that way. I found more threads with similar problems, but this seems to be an error on server side. Thanks, folks.
